# Trying to parse a line read from an input file

Tags: c++, algorithm, input

I have a problem regarding reading input lines from a file. Which is quite a simple task I can manage but the problem is **input file lines can consist of words and numbers** which then I have to read them seperately and store them in different variables. Let me give an example(italics):

```
BOOK 100
PENCIL      45
LAPTOP   49
SPOON             34
```

The reading operation would work regardless of how many spaces there between the Word and the numbers.

I have written this piece of code to read lines directly. But I do not know how to parse them according to the information I gave up.

```
string fileName;
        cout << "Enter the name of the file: ";
        cin >> fileName;

        ifstream file;
        file.open(fileName);

        while(file.fail())
        {
            cout << "enter file name correctly:";
            cin >> fileName;
            file.open(fileName);
        }

        string line;
        int points;


        while(!file.eof())
        {
            getline(file, line);
            stringstream ss(line);

                    *I do not know what to do here :)*
                    }
```

Comment: `eof()` is the cause of no end of trouble. Try instead `while (std::getline(file, line) { ... use line }`

Answer (score 3):

> But I do not know how to parse them according to the information I gave up.

Thats quite simple, see below example:

```
std::stringstream ss("SPOON             34");
std::string s;
int n;
if (ss >> s >> n) {
    std::cout << s <<"\n";
    std::cout << n <<"\n";
}
```

outputs:

```
SPOON
34
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sscanf`.

```
char name[100];
int number;
sscanf(line, "%s %d", name, &number);
printf("%s, %d", name, number);
```

Now I am not sure if this really C++ish. The alternative being using `stringstreams` like you have started.